# Need find the percentage utilization for numeric column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to find the maximum length can numeric value can store and the percentage utilization of that numeric column in a table. So can anyone help me to find the percentage utilization of numeric column in a table in oracle

Select char_length
From user_tab_column

Comment: Just because a `NUMBER(X, Y)` column can be stored in a maximum of about ⎡½X⎤+1 bytes does not mean that it will always be stored in that many bytes. It is stored using the minimum necessary to represent the numeric value. Are you asking to find the actual byte length of each value and compare that to the theoretical maximum byte length or are you asking something else?